# jQuery: highest level elements that contain x

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for a way to select elements that contain a certain element and then filter the results to get only the highest level. Difficult to explain but made easier with an example:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three" class="find-me"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="four">
    <div id="five" class="find-me"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, I would want my set to contain #one and #four. If I try to do something like this:

```
var elements = $('div').has('.find-me');
```

I get elements #one, #two and #four.

Note: By 'highest level' relates to the topmost element in the first selector, `$('div')` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the definition of what the `highest level` is, is a bit ambiguous because in practice if there is any `.find-me` in your page the highest level parent would be `html` tag! which is useless.

By defining your problem more specifically you can come up with a clearer definition for this `highest-definition` and for example say `the farthest div parent` et. and in order to traverse parents of an element you can use `.parents()` and `.closest()` methods.

```
var farthestDiv = $(".find-me").parents("div").last();
```

obviously if you have more than one occurances of `find-me` you need to run this in a `.each()` loop.

see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GsQDb/3/

Comment: Good point - I guess it's the highest level of the first set; `$('div')` in this case. I like the thought of doing it 'backwards' like this. Speed is a big issue on this page (2mb of html to traverse) so would be interested in the speed difference between this answer and the answer by @karnyj

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "top level", you mean a direct descendant of the body tag, you can use this one liner.  It finds all objects with a `.find-me` class, then searches the parents for a tag that is a descendant of the body tag (which will be the top level).

```
$(".find-me").parents("body > *")
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9LF6u/

This has these advantages:

1. Any type of tag can be the top level tag (not just a div)
2. It should be one of the faster ways to do it since it finds the `.find-me` objects (which will be a fast operation internally in most browsers via `getElementsByClassName`) and just walks up their parent hierarchy.
3. It automatically handles duplicates so a given top level item will never be listed more than once.
4. If ever you want to change the definition of top level (to a container object, for example), you can just change the selector passed to the `.parents(selector)` method to reflect that change.

Comment: My unawareness of jQuery automatic duplicate handling is why I went with the regular js route in my answer :P I bow to the master

Comment: jQuery objects created via selectors of filters never have duplicates as most jQuery methods end with an internal call to `.unique()` which filters out dups and puts the selectors in document order.

Answer (score 1):

use filter to filter out elements that don't match what you want after your first selector. example:

```
var elements = $('div.find-me').filter(function(idx){ 
    return !$(this).parents('div.find-me').length;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want, it will find the elements first and then find the highest elements of those and create a jQuery object of the found highest elements.

```
var elements = $('div.find-me'), highest = [];

elements.each( function(){
var parent = this, body = document.body;

    while( parent && parent.parentNode !== body ) {
    parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    if( $.inArray( parent, highest ) < 0 ) {
    highest.push( parent );
    }
});

highest = jQuery( highest );
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D3jC8/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you put them all in one big container div, you can use:

```
$('.container div.find-me').parents($('.container').children());
```

That SHOULD work, although I don't have the chance to test it right now.

Let me know if not since there are more complex solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign a class to the top most divs?  If so you can do something like this:

```
var elements = $("div.topMost").has(".find-me");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".find-me").map(function() {
  return $(this).parents("div").last().get();
});
```